# Solaris ufs forcedirectio

Tags: oracle, solaris

I have oracle database on a Solaris 9 box.

Oracle datafiles are  stored on the ufs filesystem mounted with forcedirectio. So I'm using now only Oracle Buffer Cache.

question: is it good idea to remove forcedirectio option to improve IO performance?

Answer (score 2):

No, `forcedirectio` causes the Solaris disk buffers to be bypassed thus avoiding double buffering and speeding things up.

Removing `forcedirectio` will most likely have a negative effect on IO Performance.